# How to include native libs from another module in gradle

Tags: android, android-ndk, gradle

I'm working with Gradle and I have one module (android library) that has some native stuff in it, which i finally managed to build correctly, with this extra task:

```
task buildNative(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI sources with NDK') {
    def ndkDir = project.plugins.findPlugin('com.android.library').getNdkFolder();
    commandLine "$ndkDir\\ndk-build.cmd",
            '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath, //Change directory to his before continuing
            '-j', Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors(), //Might make it faster
            'NDK_LIBS_OUT="', file('src/main/jniLibs').absolutePath, '"', //Libs path
            'NDK_OUT="', file('build/ndkcustom/obj').absolutePath, '"' //Obj path
}
```

Now, that module includes an example app and when i run that (changed from .library to .application for the test) it worked well, so everything is getting included like it should. However, i dont want to use that example app, but want to use the natives / java classes from that module in another module, which will be my main app. Just including the module gives me acces to the java classes, but not the natives, so when i run:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("native-activity");
}
```

It gives an error that it cant load the library. How can I include the native library?

**Edit:**

My project gradle file doesnt contain anything special.

build.gradle of the library:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mobilesdkharness"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 15
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jni.srcDirs = [] //Disable automatic jni building
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

//Note: Using ndk r10c - might brake with future releases
task buildNative(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI sources with NDK') {
    def ndkDir = project.plugins.findPlugin('com.android.library').getNdkFolder();
    commandLine "$ndkDir\\ndk-build.cmd",
            '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath, //Change directory to his before continuing
            '-j', Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors(), //Might make it faster
            'NDK_LIBS_OUT="', file('src/main/jniLibs').absolutePath, '"', //Libs path
            'NDK_OUT="', file('build/ndkcustom/obj').absolutePath, '"' //Obj path
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn buildNative
}
```

build.gradle of the app (only really contains the include)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':mysdk')
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you post more information on your gradle config files from your app, project and lib ? I've got a similar setup than yours (lib with .so files required by main app) and it's working perfectly fine.

Comment: thanks, so we still have a quite similar setup... Are you sure that your libs are generated inside jniLibs/(armeabi|x86|...) folders ? Your call to ndk-build doesn't look totally right. -C should point to jni parent folder. Also, what are your gradle and android plugins versions ?